# Build an APK in Android studio to pass out like Eclipse for testing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

In ECLIPSE when you want to do a export of the project as an APK you could just do it using a generic signature from within Eclipse using like "android" as the password etc to build out the APK so you can give it to other people to install and test etc etc.

How do I do this in android studio?

Comment: You can generate a signed apk from Build -> Generate Signed APK. You'll have to set up some keystores but then you should be able to use that (it's also valid for uploading to the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio has an output directory for the binaries, you can see (and change) it at File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Paths. It's the "Compiler Output" option. There you will find your APK(s).

PS: all apps are compiled to APK.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a debug apk in builds/output/apk folder or you can generate a release apk by going: Build -> Generate Singed APk...

You need to create a password for your keychain the first time you do it, and then create the key store password, the key alias and a key password. (It's easier that it looks :))